# Resetting IntelliJ refactoring defaults

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

I have set some defaults on IntelliJ's method renaming functionality [specifically 'rename string usages'] and its causing me pain.

How do I remove these defaults? I can't find it in the project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Refactor` | `Rename` keyboard shortcut twice to get the dialog with options:

[image: rename]

Note the hint at the bottom of the popup.